# Trigger thumbnails only for certain resolution (desktop) for fancybox 3.1

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

Is there a way, and if so how, to trigger the grid with thumbnails to appear only based on a resolution?
Basically, I don't want to set it to be automatic since that would mean phones as well, but I would like it to open automatically for desktop or tablets. Preferably through using viewport / css to identify resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CSS media query to target the element containing your thumbnail grid. For example:

```
@media (max-width: 576px) {
    /* Hide element under 576px width */
    .thumbnail-grid-selector {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

MDN has information on media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Bootstrap has some examples of breakpoints for various devices: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

You can either hide button and thumbnail grid using CSS (see bottom of thumbs.css for sample) or disable on mobile devices entirely:

```
mobile : {
  thumbs : false
}
```

Comment: Is there a way o just set it to automatic only on a certain resolution? I'd still like to have people use it for mobile, if they decide to do so, so I don't want to disable it completely.